# Forcing all Internet Traffic OverVPN, Allowing LAN Access

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables

I have an Ubuntu Box on my LAN that I would like to:

- Send all external traffic over an OpenVPN connection (tun0)
- Deny all external traffic if the OpenVPN connection should fail
- Allow all internal traffic to my 192.168.0.0 network

Any ideas on where I can get some example iptables configurations for this type of setup?

Comment: So what options have you tried to use? What's your current iptables ruleset? What's your OpenVPN config? What's your routing set to? There's all sorts of information out there on the web for you to do some basic attempts at setting it up, and I whole-heartedly recommend that you try some and figure out what each do so that you actually learn something.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you some broad architectural comments, because I think you might need some clarification on a few things.

> Send all external traffic over an OpenVPN connection (tun0)

You will want your Ubuntu box to be the gateway/router. You will set the router's default gateway to be `tun0` so that it sends all traffic to your endpoint.

> Deny all external traffic if the OpenVPN connection should fail

That will happen implicitly if your Ubuntu machine is the router with a default gateway of the IP address across the tunnel. No tunnel, no gateway!

> Allow all internal traffic to my 192.168.0.0 network

Your router won't touch LAN traffic. That's a switching issue. As long as you have switches, you're golden. Scratch this one off of your list of things to do to your Ubuntu box.

> Any ideas on where I can get some example iptables configurations for
>   this type of setup?

In all seriously, with no intention to be patronizing, Google is going to help you out immensely. The topics you have brought up are so broad that anything I search for on your behalf has a 50/50 chance of being pertinent to you. Search around, and you'll find great resources out there. Michael Rash has a good book on Linux Firewalls as of this post. Robin Nixon has a book on Ubuntu. Markus Feilner and Norbert Graf have a starter book on OpenVPN. However, all of those suggestions are subject to change as time marches on.

Your fingers and a search engine (as well as user groups and IRC channels) are going to be better point-in-time guides to what is pertinent.